# How to constrain optimization based on number of negative values of variable in pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I'm working with a pyomo model (mostly written by someone else, to be updated by me) that optimizes electric vehicle charging (ie, how much power will a vehicle import or export at a given timestep). The optimization variable (u) is power, and the objective is to minimize total charging cost given the charging cost at each timestep.

I'm trying to write a new optimization function to limit the number of times that the model will allow each vehicle to *export* power (ie, to set u < 0). I've written a constraint called max_call_rule that counts the number of times u < 0, and constrains it to be less than a given value (max_calls) for each vehicle. (max_calls is a dictionary with a label for each vehicle paired with an integer value for the number of calls allowed.)

The code is very long, but I've put the core pieces below:

```
model.u = Var(model.t, model.v, domain=Integers, doc='Power used')
model.max_calls = Param(model.v, initialize = max_calls)

def max_call_rule(model, v):
      return len([x for x in [model.u[t, v] for t in model.t] if x < 0]) <= model.max_calls[v]
model.max_call_rule = Constraint(model.v, rule=max_call_rule, doc='Max call rule')
```

This approach doesn't work--I get the following error when I try to run the code.

> ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint max_call_rule
>       with index 16: ValueError: Cannot create an InequalityExpression with more
>       than 3 terms.
>
> ERROR: Constructing component 'max_call_rule' from data=None failed:
>       ValueError: Cannot create an InequalityExpression with more than 3 terms.

I'm new to working with pyomo and suspect that this error means that I'm trying to do something that fundamentally won't work with an optimization program. So--**is there a better way for me to constrain the number of times that my variable u can be less than 0?**

Comment: Counting in general needs binary variables. If the model is a MIP notice that all constraints need to be linear.

Comment: Ah, of course @ErwinKalvelagen. That makes sense; thank you. Is there any way people typically approximate something binary as a linear constraint? (I can't imagine I'm the only one who's ever wanted to do this.) Or would I really need to reorient my constraint differently? I can think of some ways to do this that would be acceptable, but just wondering what my options would be if I couldn't...

Comment: You need to introduce binary variables `b[t,v]` with the condition `u[t,v]<=-1 =>b[t,v]=1`. Then you can do `sum(t, b[t,v]) <= max_calls[v]`. This is all very standard mip modeling. It looks you are not familiar with this, so you probably should tell your supervisor that you are missing some expertise in this respect (there is nothing wrong with that: it is unrealistic to assume everyone is familiar with MIP modeling). The solution is to do some training, or hire people with appropriate expertise.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, I'm definitely no expert in MIP modeling. If you have any training resources to recommend, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: There are some online courses on mixed-integer programming. Sorry, I have no recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is minimize the *number of times vehicles are exporting power*, you can introduce a binary variable that allows/disallows vehicles discharging. You want this variable to be indexed over time and vehicles.

Note that if the rest of your model is LP (linear, without any integer variables), this will turn it into a MIP/MILP. There's a significant difference in terms of computational effort required to solve, and the types of solvers you can use. The larger the problems, the bigger the difference this will make. I'm not sure why `u` is currently set as `Integers`, that seems quite strange given it represents power.

```py
model.allowed_to_discharge = Var(model.t, model.v, within=Boolean)

def enforce_vehicle_discharging_logic_rule(model, t, v):
    """
    When `allowed_to_discharge[t,v]` is 1, 
    this constraint doesn't have any effect.
    When `allowed_to_discharge[t,v]` is 1, u[t,v] >= 0.
    Note that 1e9 is just a "big M", i.e. any big number
    that you're sure exceeds the maximum value of `model.u`.
    """
    return model.u[t,v] >= 0 - model.allowed_to_discharge[t,v] * 1e9

model.enforce_vehicle_discharging_logic = Constraint(
    model.t, model.v, rule=enforce_vehicle_discharging_logic_rule
)
```

Now that you have the binary variable, you can count the events, and specifically you can assign a cost to such events and add it to your objective function (just in case, you can only have *one* objective function, so you're just adding a "component" to it, not adding a second objective function).

```py
def objective_rule(model):
    return ( 
        ... # the same objective function as before
        + sum(model.u[t, v] for t in model.t for v in model.v) * model.cost_of_discharge_event
    )
model.objective = Objective(rule=objective_rule)
```

If what you instead of what you add to your objective function is a cost associated to the *total energy discharged by the vehicles* (instead of the number of events), you want to introduce two separate variables for charging and discharging - both non-negative, and then define the "net discharge" (which right now you call `u`) as an `Expression` which is the difference between discharge and charge.

You can then add a cost component to your objective function that is the sum of all the *discharge* power, and multiply it by the cost associated with it.